# Moving thumbnails with zoom

Tags: jquery, zooming, move, thumbnails

Is there a jquery script like on this page: http://hellomonday.com/ ?

I need a 4 rows with thumbnails (that i can move right/left) and when i click them it will zoom and show me big images with some description.

Comment: I guess your question should be asked here: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: That's a really horrible website.